# How to solve equations involving multiple floors of the same variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve equations of this type:

$$\lfloor1x\rfloor+\lfloor2x\rfloor+\lfloor3x\rfloor+\lfloor4x\rfloor+\lfloor5x\rfloor=10$$

Comment: Good for you.  To that end, what have you tried?  And did you have a question?

Comment: I do not know where to start at all. Adding them seems terrible, and the only way I can think is brute-forcing it...

Comment: **Hint**: $x-1<\lfloor x \rfloor\leq x$. We can estimate $x$.

Comment: If nothing else you can narrow the range of possible solutions, as @Adam suggests.  Note that the left hand side is a (weakly) increasing function of $x$.  E.g. since setting $x=10$ gives a value that is too large, any solution must be... less than $10$.

Comment: @hardmath $x = 1$ is already too large.

Comment: Does anyone know of any techniques besides brute force computation? I can tell you it's probably more than 0.5, but less than 1.

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 now go one step ahead just check it for 3/4 which gives 9 thus the solution is between 0.75 and 1

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 I followed your approach using the gradient descent techinque and get 0.8, sometimes 0.9 by assuming the cost as the output of the function and gradient as 10 minus the cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it like there are five rotating spinners, where the $i^{th}$ spinner makes $i$ revolutions per minute.  All spinners start at the same position at $x=0$ minutes. The first spinner completes a revolution every $60$ seconds, the second every $30$ seconds, etc. The number of revolutions completed at time $x$ by the $i^{th}$ spinner is $\lfloor ix\rfloor$, so your problem is to find all of the times where the combined total of revolutions is $10.$

Make a schedule of all the times a revolution is completed (a "tick"):

```
Spinner 1 ...........................................................x
Spinner 2 .............................x.............................x
Spinner 3 ...................x...................x...................x
Spinner 4 ..............x..............x..............x..............x
Spinner 5 ...........x...........x...........x...........x...........x
```

Each `.` is one second, and each `x` is a tick. We see that the $10^{th}$ tick occurs when Spinner 5 makes its penultimate tick at $x=0.8$ minutes $=48$ seconds. Therefore, the set of times for which there are $10$ ticks total is $x\in [0.8,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from the following.

$x=[x]+\{x\}$ and consider number of cases:

1. $0\leq\{x\}<\frac{1}{5};$
2. $\frac{1}{5}\leq\{x\}<\frac{2}{5};$

$.$

$.$

$.$

Good luck!

Also, the left side increases!

Comment: Wouldn't you want a finer partition than that? The parts in this partition will make $\lfloor 4x \rfloor$ annoying to keep track of, for example.

Comment: @Theo Bendit It's the standard notation. $[x]$ and $\lfloor {x}\rfloor$ they are the same. There is also $\lceil x\rceil$ of course, but it's another story. If you say about the essence of my hint then it's the hint only. I did not write all cases.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg $ \lfloor x \rfloor $ to me means floor function where I have seen $ [x] $ as just being used as brackets, equivalent to $ (x) $.

Comment: @Warren Hill We always know from the context about which thing we say.